# Partial fractions, disagreement with Wolfram Alpha

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On my math homework, I have this problem, and WolframAlpha says that $A=-\frac{1}{7}$ and $B=\frac{1}{7}$. However, while solving the problem on my own, I found a restriction that $A \neq -B$. How is it that this answer works? The problem in question is:
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2 - 3 x - 10} = \dfrac{A}{x+2} + \dfrac{B}{x - 5}$$

Comment: How did you come up with your restriction?

Comment: Your link solves your own question. Look at the line beneath the $A=-\frac 17$ etc, and you see a second condition from which answers surface.

Comment: while solving the problem, I managed to solve for x. The denominator was A+B, and the denominator cannot be 0, so A≠-B

Comment: If you managed to solve for $x$, then you were doing the wrong problem. The problem is to find $A,B$ so that the equation holds for *all* $x$. It's a little like saying you solved for $x$ in $x+x=Ax$.

Comment: For large $x$ the fraction will tend to zero as $\sim 1/x^2$, while each term in the partial fraction expansion goes to zero as $\sim 1/x$. This means that the leading asymptotic behavior of the two terms must cancel out and that means that A must equal minus B.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is more like solving $0x+1=1$ for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "solved for $x$," I presume you got something like $$(A+B)x=5A-2B+1$$ and then said, now we must divide both sides by $A+B$, but that's only allowed if $A+B\ne0$. But in fact the displayed equation is not meant to be solved for $x$; it's meant to hold for *all* values of $x$. The only way that can happen is for both $A+B$ and $5A-2B+1$ to be zero. That leads, as in the other answers that have been posted, to what Wolfram gave you.

Now, you ask, "How is it that this answer works?" Well, it's very easy to see how it works: you just work out $${-1/7\over x+2}+{1/7\over x-5}$$ and see that you get $1/(x^2-3x-10)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full derivation: $$\frac{1}{x^2-3x-10}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x-5}\implies$$ $$(x+2)(x-5)\left(\frac{1}{x^2-3x-10}\right)=(x+2)(x-5)\left(\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x-5}\right)\implies$$ $$1=A(x-5)+B(x+2)=A(x)-5A+B(x)+2B=x(A+B)+1(2B-5A)$$

Hence we need $A+B=0\space\text{and}\space2B-5A=1$. So substitute $A=-B$ into the second equation: $$2B-5(-B)=1\implies7B=1\implies B=\frac{1}{7}$$

But we have the condition that $A+B=0$ and we know $B=\frac{1}{7},$ hence $$A+\frac{1}{7}=0\implies A=-\frac{1}{7}$$ Thus $$\frac{1}{x^2-3x-10}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x-5}=\frac{1}{7(x-5)}-\frac{1}{7(x+2)}$$

Comment: Alternatively, once you get to $1=A(x-5)+B(x+2)$, you can substitute $x=5$ to get $B=1/7$, and $x=-2$ to get $A=-1/7$.

Answer (score 1):

To find $A$ and $B$:

Note that

$(x + 2)(x - 5) = x^2 -3x - 10; \tag 1$

then from

$\dfrac{1}{x^2 -3x - 10} = \dfrac{A}{x + 2} + \dfrac{B}{x - 5} \tag 2$

we have

$A(x - 5) + B(x + 2) = \dfrac{(x + 2)(x - 5)}{x^2 -3x - 10} = 1; \tag 3$

this may be written

$(A + B)x + (2B - 5A) = 1, \tag 4$

whence

$A + B = 0 \Longrightarrow B = -A, \tag 5$

so that

$-7A = 2(-A) - 5A = 2B -5A = 1 \Longrightarrow A = -\dfrac{1}{7}, \; B = \dfrac{1}{7}; \tag 6$

we check:

$\dfrac{A}{x + 2} + \dfrac{B}{x - 5} = -\dfrac{1}{7}\dfrac{1}{x + 2} + \dfrac{1}{7}\dfrac{1}{x - 5} = \dfrac{1}{7} \left ( \dfrac{1}{x - 5} - \dfrac{1}{x + 2} \right )$
$= \dfrac{1}{7}\left ( \dfrac{x + 2}{x^2 -3x - 10} - \dfrac{x - 5}{x^2 -3x - 10} \right ) = \dfrac{1}{7}\dfrac{7}{x^2 -3x - 10} = \dfrac{1}{x^2 -3x - 10}. \tag 7$